# A script to ssh into a remote folder and check all files?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a public/private key pair set up so I can ssh to a remote server without having to log in. I'm trying to write a shell script that will list all the folders in a particular directory on the remote server. My question is: how do I specify the remote location? Here's what I've got:

```
 #!/bin/bash

for file in myname@example.com:dir/*
do
if [ -d "$file" ]
then
echo $file;
fi
done
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in `ssh myname@example.com 'ls -d dir/*/'`
do
    echo $file;
done
```

Or simply:

```
ssh myname@example.com 'ls -d dir/*/'
```

Explanation:

- The *ssh* command accepts an optional command after the hostname and, if a command is provided, it executes that command on login instead of the login shell; ssh then simply passes on the stdout from the command as its own stdout. Here we are simply passing the *ls* command.
- ls -d dir/*/ is a trick to make ls skip regular files and list out only the directories.

Comment: hi, is there a way to add an awk to get only the file names ? I'm kind of stucked on it because this command : for file in `ssh ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST} 'ls -l /path/to/dir/ | awk "{print $9}"'` do... does not seems to work.... thanks :)